# Data from service to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I created a service which asynchronously takes some data and saves it as

```
someitem = { something: 'a', somethingelse: 'b'}
```

inside the service.
When i console.log `service.someitem`, it logs as supposed, but when I try to assign it to `$scope = service.someitem` it does not bind it with the template?

---

edit. now i found my mistake: i'm overriting the `$scope` object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your whole `$scope` with `$scope = service.someitem` it should be rather
`$scope.modelToUse = service.someitem`

Comment: found it in the same time!:) though its my own answer i'll accept:-)